# Is it possible to know the size of a variable that is being created while the function is running?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, time-series, bigdata

I am very new to R and I was exploring a function in a library that download data from a server and leaves the data as dataframe.

The data are stored in a variable but as I want to download a big time series, I get an error in the function because exceeds the variable size as I understood.

I though making an iteration so the data can be stored in different variables as soon as exceed the size of the variable that is being create in the function.

So I would like to know if is it possible to know the size of the variable while the function is running, in order to be able to do it a condition?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `object.size()`

Comment: A single variable doesn't have a memory limit. It's R itself that has a memory limit. You can't store more data in an active session than you have RAM in your computer. Vectors may have a max length, but not really a max size. If you are getting out-of-memory errors, writing to a different variable isn't going to help I'm afraid.

Comment: If you are using a SQL Database on the Server, and want to perform some filtering, joining or grouping. you could use dbplyr from the tidyverse. It will perform those operations on the databse server for you: https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dbplyr.html